# using split to print last character before the delimeter

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have few files named as trace0.log,  trace1.log, trace2.log, trace3.log…. trace8.log. I wanted to capture the values (0,1,2,3…8) which are in the file names and store into a variable and later add 1 to each, so I can rename them (from higher to lower).

Is there an easy way of doing this?

For example:

```
trace8.log becomes trace9.log
trace7.log becomes trace8.log
…
…
trace1.log becomes trace2.log
trace0.log becomes trace1.log
```

Script:

```
$Path = "E:\Files\"
$F = Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter *.log 
$F.Name
$FNSplit = $F.Name.Split(".")[1]
$FNSplit
```

Right now, it prints the first string after the split (I.e log).

Comment: $F.Name[-1] will capture the last character of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex to parse the file name (there may be more then 9 files).

Here an example where I retrieve all log files using the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet, sort them descending by the number (otherwise, you would get an error when you rename the file because the file already exists) and finally rename the file using a regex and the [Rename-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113382) cmdlet:

```
$Path = 'E:\Files\'
gci $Path -Filter *.log |
    sort { [int][regex]::Match($_.BaseName, '(.*?)(\d+)').Groups[2].Value } -Descending | 
     % {
        $regexResult = [regex]::Match($_.Name,'(.*?)(\d+)\.(.*)');
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}{1}.{2}' -f $regexResult.Groups[1].Value, ([int]$regexResult.Groups[2].Value +1), $regexResult.Groups[3].Value)
    }
```